# json rpc in tornado web server

Tags: extjs, extjs4, rpc, tornado, json-rpc

I'm implementing web application in python using tornado web server with javascript client (using extjs). What is the best framework to implement rpc in such application?

During search I found [tornadorpc](http://code.google.com/p/tornadorpc/) library but I'm afraid it won't be useful because it's too old (last commit 2 years ago, and four mails in mailing list) and [autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/python) which needs Twisted (Twisted has slower websockets than Tornado, which is also important too me).

Any help? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want from tornado-rpc server? How you can measure usefulness?

[Tornado RPC](https://github.com/joshmarshall/tornadorpc) just works and works fine. It supports jsonrpc. You can fork and improve it.

Also you can combine twisted and tornado, and use twisted for rpc and tornado for websockets.

Comment: Thanks. After research I still didn't find any better solution than tornadorpc so I'll probably do as you said - improve it. Do you also know good json implementation for the client side?

Comment: Json is native for client side..  I believe, that extjs has cool wrappers for it.